# Prove B is a subset of D

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let A,B,C and D be four sets.

Prove that if $A\cup B \subseteq C\cup D$, $A\cap B = \varnothing$, and $C\subseteq A$  then $B\subseteq D$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B$ is empty, then $B\subseteq D$ trivially. Suppose, then, that $B$ is non-empty and $x\in B$. Then,
\begin{align*}
x\in B\subseteq A\cup B\subseteq C\cup D.
\end{align*}
If $x\notin D$, then it must be the case that $x\in C$. Also, $x\in A$, since $C\subseteq A$. Therefore, $x\in A\cap B=\varnothing$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, it must be the case that $x\in D$.

In sum, $x\in B$ necessarily implies that $x\in D$, so that $B\subseteq D$. $\quad\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

$C\subseteq A$ and $A \cap B = \varnothing$, what does this tell you about $B \cap C$?

And you know that $B \subseteq C \cup D$ so now just put it together.